# Can't resize textarea when it's disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a textarea that is disabled to stop the user editing the text but this also disables the resize of the textarea. I can't drag out the textarea to see all the text in the box.

```
 <textarea runat="server" id="txtCollectionInstructions" style="height:17px; width:275px" disabled="disabled" ></textarea>
```

Is there a way to keep the textarea disabled to they can't edit the text but still be able to resize the textarea?

Comment: is `disabled` disable the resize?? https://jsfiddle.net/y3cgtrtu/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef It doesn't disable the resize if there is no text but when there is text I can't resize it. See example jsfiddle.net/p2txwLf5

Comment: I see .. I think you need to use `readonly` instead of `disabled` .. something like http://jsfiddle.net/p2txwLf5/4/

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thank you this worked

Answer (score 3):

You can set `resize:both;` within the CSS which should hopefully allow you to resize the `textarea`:

```css
textarea {
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
 <textarea runat="server" id="txtCollectionInstructions" style="height:17px; width:275px" disabled="disabled" ></textarea>
```

### Update

If this is not a sufficient solution in terms of the `textarea` field not being able to be resized when you have overlapping content, then it could be possible to change the `textarea` field to a `div` and if it is wished, use the CSS as above as well as style the `div` as a `textarea` field (i.e. light grey `border` with a small `border-radius` and sufient `padding`). This would give you disabled content that could be resized if needed.

```css
    div {
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
        border:1px solid #CCC;
        border-radius:4px;
        padding:10px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:14px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="txtCollectionInstructions" style="height:17px; width:275px" >This is text...</textarea>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: That works if the textarea doesn't have any text in it but when there is text I can't resize it. See example https://jsfiddle.net/p2txwLf5/

Comment: Can I ask what the use case is? One option (if possible) would be to change the textarea for a div and set the resize as above. This would mean you could have your disabled content but the resize will mean the div's width and height can be changed?

Comment: What do you mean use case? If there are 3 lines entered into the textarea but it's disabled I can't resize the textarea so I can't see all the lines. I would prefer to keep the textareas instead of changing to div

Comment: use case would be how are you using this. Is there a specific reason as to why not use a div instead as you would still be able to style the text to look as a textarea field by adding a light grey border, sufficient padding and a slight border-radius for the corners. My hope was that you have code that you are able to change (i.e. change the textarea for a div) so hopefully if this is possible, this would be a legit solution to go with.